# Upload image with specif size, it should support all Aspect Ratios

Tags: java, css, image, angular6

I am uploading Image size is 1160 * 250, once the image is uploaded I will use many places but different ratio sizes, like Thumbnails and Full Images.

I am Using CSS Properties

```
object-fit: Cover
```

I was tried using CSS Properties like object-fit: Cover

```
<img _ngcontent-c3="" alt="Image" class="img-fluid ng-star-inserted" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/sABFEdWNreQABAAQAAABkAAD">

.class{
    width : 100%;
    height:350px;
    object-fit :cover
}
```

Images are not getting Properly as expected, need a Complete image. but cropping

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: use

```
object-fit: contain
```

Option 2:
Also try using `max-width`, `min-width` and `max-height` `min-height` to set the image for aspect ratio as these properties work when you try to get image form 3rd party like Insta...

Comment: try second option if not then can you please provide code-pen OR fiddle of your complete code with working link of image?